# How do I recover my data from my ZFS formatted drive?

Tags: boot, 20.04, data-recovery, zfs

A few days ago my computer filled up, I was at someone's house for new years, so I figure I'd just export some stuff once I got home.  I got home, but my computer was off, so I try to boot it, ~20 minutes go by, and it still hasn't booted, so I check around and sure enough, when a ZFS drive fills up, it stops booting, this isn't my problem though, I've been meaning to switch flavours for a while and this seemed like the perfect opportunity, I just need my data.

Every time I run zpool import on the partition the entire command prompt freezes, to the point that I can't even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> out of the command, I've tried a LOT of zpool and zfs commands and nothing's worked so far, I even tried the -F flag on zpool; nada.  Any help is much appreciated, I know that ZFS is an experimental feature, but I think that making it so that your computer doesn't stop booting once your drive fills up is something canonical might want to look into.

I'm on 20.04LTS, nothing fancy, I just chose the default zfs option.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual "solution" per se, but perhaps some food for thought perhaps. ;-)

I think you may just need to be a little more patient with ZFS (and maybe add some more RAM too!) and let it do it's work... :-)

If, as you say, you are at 100% capacity for your zpool, ZFS could potentially be INCREDIBLY SLOW!

The volume I have doesn't seem very big, and it's not all that "full" either - yet it still takes a long time to complete a scrub.

Just imagine how much information is being processed by ZFS when the data's integrity is dependant on a Merkle tree - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree

So, why might it be slow?

At least two easy reasons (both will compound being close to 100% capacity!):

- No data specific datesets (eg. big files in one dataset, small files in another)
- The blocksize is not tuned for the content of the dataset - see above point, and the Merkle tree link.

---

```
truenas% zpool list Storage
NAME      SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
Storage  14.5T  10.9T  3.66T        -         -     0%    74%  1.00x    ONLINE  /mnt

truenas% zfs list Storage
NAME      USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
Storage  5.27T  1.55T      192K  /mnt/Storage

truenas% zpool status Storage | grep scrub
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 05:33:26 with 0 errors on Sun Jan 10 05:33:26 2021
```

---

While this is an old example, it could still be somewhat relevant for you - we have no idea what the configuration of your system is, or what your pool consists of in terms of files and layout etc.

https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/864

See also:
https://openzfs.org/wiki/System_Administration#Data_Integrity
https://youtu.be/Js535LqapFE

BTW: Not being able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is a good thing when it comes to your filesystem. Although granted, sometimes you wish you could <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> especially the instant you discover you've had an "Oops!" moment!

EDIT: This may also be why the import is taking so long - https://serverfault.com/a/213866/255055